# Regex used to interleave head and tail of a list

Tags: regex, notepad++

I recently had to do this, and spent about 60 seconds writing up a C# program to do it, so please do not tell me there is an easier way. I know there is an easier way since I've done it. I just want to know if this can be done purely with regex.

I have a string that contains a series of elements separated by a delimiter.

The number of delimited elements is always even.

I always know the total number of elements.

Can I use a single regex replace pattern (which can be run any number of times) so that I interleave the Head and Tail elements?

Example

8 elements

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
```

Becomes

```
A, H, B, G, C, F, D, E
```

EDIT:

I've gotten a few answers which include dynamically building the pattern. This is what I was looking to avoid (pretty much any code), but I blame myself for not being clear enough in my original question.

I should have said

I wanted to be able to write a pattern that I could use in notepad++ regex replace without opening up another application or writing any code

Comment: Only having spent 60 seconds? Isn't it a bit to early to call quits? However, that isn't something that can be done solely with regex.

Comment: Are the elements comma separated in the string? Why not put them in an array?

Comment: The 60 seconds was to write a loop to do this another way, not the regex. I was just saying this so that people didn't tell me to split the string into a couple arrays and loop through them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done from within Notepad++ by following these steps:

1. Repeatedly replace `(\w+)((?:, \w+)*)(, \w+)` with `$1!%!$3!%!$2` until no more matches are found.
2. Replace all instance of `!%!` with <nothing>.

Comment: BINGO! This did it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, kinda. The matching regex would be "([^,]+(?:,|$))+", however the replace string would have to be dynamically built like "$1$8$2$7$3$6$4$5". However, if you dynamically build the string "replace string", you might as well just split the string and manually concat at that point.

Comment: yeah, I kinda figured that would be the case. I was trying to avoid any dynamic pattern generation. The idea is that I wanted to be able to write a pattern that I could use in notepad++ regex replace without opening up another application or writing any code. I know it's not the right way to do this, just a kind of thought experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my $N = 8;
my $str = "A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H";
$str =~ s|((?:\w,?\s*){$N})|
  my @items = split ',\s+', $1;
  join ', ', map { $items[$_], $items[-($_+1)] } 0..($N/2 - 1)
|e;
```

To accomodate your updated question: How to avoid the preset `$N` variable? You could do this:

```
$str =~ s|((?:\w,?\s*){8})|
  my @items = split ',\s+', $1;
  join ', ', map { $items[$_], $items[-($_+1)] } 0..3)
|e;
```

Now you have to hardcode the numbers 8 and 4-1 into the regex..
Is that what you was looking for?

You can avoid having to enter the number 3 by doing this:

```
$str =~ s|((?:\w,?\s*){8})|
  my @items = split ',\s+', $1;
  my $N = scalar @items;
  join ', ', map { $items[$_], $items[-($_+1)] } 0..($N/2 - 1)
|e;
```

Now you only have to hardcode the number 8..

Comment: Hardcoding the count works for me. I think this is the closest I'm going to get and kinda confirms that I need some sort of non-regex instruction to do this.